# Python Django.Как сделать так ,чтобы при определенном количестве категории было определенное количество выпадающих элементов

Tags: html, python, django, bootstrap

Есть bootstrap выпадающие элементы

```
`<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Кнопка выпадающего списка
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>`
```

И есть Python Django модель:

```
name_categories = models.CharField('Название категории', max_length = 200)
```

Как сделать так ,чтобы при определенном количестве категории было определенное количество выпадающих элементов,а также как вывести текст поля name_categories в выпадающие элементы.
Заранее благодарю за ответ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого вам в форму нужно передать объекты, содержащие `name_categories`:

`objects = list(ModelName.objects.all())`

(Не уверен, что `list()` здесь необходим)

```
return render(request, 'template.html', {'objects': objects})
```

В шаблоне:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Кнопка выпадающего списка
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    {% for object in objects %}
         <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{ object.name_categories }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
```

Либо можете сразу передать туда лист из `name_categories`, тогда в шаблоне будет

```
         <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{ object }}</a>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное)Помогло

Comment: Помогите пожалуйста  - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1103946/python-django-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b2